# How is the number of Unicoins gained from mining determined?

Tags: support, unicoins

I notice that, sometimes, when mining for Unicoins, I'll get several (I've noticed, I think, up to six at once).

I'm wondering, is this based on how quickly I click on the rocks, randomly determined, or some other system?

Comment: Is this an actual new thing or are the coins an April Fools joke?

Comment: This question is probably better off on meta.

Comment: judging by some of the things it "does"....I'm saying its a joke

Comment: It's an April Fools joke, fairly obviously. But other April Fools jokes are considered on topic.

Comment: @Gigazelle It's a game that extends beyond Arqade (it's on other SE sites).

Comment: [This might be a good read on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins)

Comment: If Google doodles are considered "games", this probably should be too.

Comment: @bwarner those doodles often have actual gameplay, though. Clicking a rock a bunch of times can hardly be called that.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what cookie clicker is though - clicking on a cookie a bunch of times? Wasn't the game "Curiosity" just tapping on blocks?

Comment: why is this on meta?

Comment: It got migrated. I assume it's related to Gigazelle's suggestion. Maybe it came up in chat or another meta and the decision was made to move it here or maybe it was just the will of the unicorns. Either way, it's clearly here because some entity with the ability to migrate it here did so. If the unicorn functionality disappears Tomorrow, then the question would become hard to address anyways so I understand the move.

Answer (score 7):

The more soul and heart you pour in the mining operation, the better aligned the stars are, the more fully convinced you are of the existence of unicorns, the more far removed you are from the heresy that's unicorns in MLP, the better skilled you are in making soulfully relevant freehanded red circles, the more reputation you have, the more you will be rewarded in your quest for enlightenment.